# UIScrollView with multiply controls doesnt scroll when trying to swipe from place where control exists

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

This is how my `UIScrollView` looks like:

[image]

Yellow mean intearctive controls. Once this controller is loaded, I try to swipe it up, but it lacks, i do not know why. When I try a few times, then it moves. Why it happens like that?

**EDIT:**

Actually it doesn't move when I try to swipe it from the place where yellow control exists.

Comment: [UIScrollview documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches) describes in details how a scroll view responds to touches. To analyze the problem you can start with checking the value of `delaysContentTouches` and overriding touch handling methods of the scroll view's and some of its subviews.

Comment: You were right. `delaysContentTouches` helped. Thanks.